# Time missmatch when using NetCDF4

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a netcdf file with a time variable `time`. When I print this variable I get this:

```
    <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 time(time)
    long_name: time
    units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0
    calendar: gregorian
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (31,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
```

I would like to see the dates stored in my `time` variable. If I type and run `print(time[:])` I will not really be able to see the dates of my `time` variable. Instead I will see this:

```
[1004406. 1004430. 1004454. 1004478. 1004502. 1004526. 1004550. 1004574.
 1004598. 1004622. 1004646. 1004670. 1004694. 1004718. 1004742. 1004766.
 1004790. 1004814. 1004838. 1004862. 1004886. 1004910. 1004934. 1004958.
 1004982. 1005006. 1005030. 1005054. 1005078. 1005102. 1005126.]
```

Now, This is what I have done to see the time in a date format:

```
dtime = nc.num2date(time[:],time.units)
```

However, when I print `dtime` this is my result:

```
[cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)
 cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 8, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)...
```

Why is it showing 2014 instead of 1990 and how can I fix this using ndtcdf4?

I do not know what is happening on the background.

Comment: `1004406 / 8760 + 1900 = 2014.658`. so `num2date` appears to me to be working correctly given these values. why do you expect to see 1990? that said, I'd recommend using xarray to work with netcdfs, e.g. using [`xr.open_dataset`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html) - it includes support for netCDF4 files and will convert dates and handle coordinate labels like this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the time values are `hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0` meaning that for instance if you take the first value 1004406, it should correspond to:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime(1900,1,1,)+datetime.timedelta(seconds=1004406*3600)
```

i.e. `datetime.datetime(2014,8,1,6,0)` exactly as you get it. Why should it be 1990 instead of 2014?

I suggest using `num2date` with following options:

only_use_cftime_datetimes=False and only_use_python_datetimes=True.

Latter would give `dtime` as `datetime` objects, which can be easily used with `matplotlib`. Somehow the `cftime` are not so easily supported...

So, in your script:

```
dtime = nc.num2date(time[:],time.units,only_use_cftime_datetimes=False,only_use_python_datetimes=True)
```